# create simple encryption code in PHP by replacing characters

Tags: php, arrays, string, encryption, char

I'm new in PHP.

I want to make a simple encryption function in PHP that change a string to new string by changing characters.

For doing this, I create two arrays of characters.

In the first array I assign all characters and sorting them like :

```
$true_chars = array('a','b','c','d','e');
```

In another array, I change the position of the characters.

```
$fake_chars = array('c','d','a','e','b');
```

My goal is, when the function gets the right string,  change the string characters by  Replacing the second array.

For example, my string is `acdc` , the encryption function compares `acdc` characters by the first array to get true index's (if need) and then replace by second array index and change it to `caea`.

how actually can I do that?

Comment: loop through the characters, find the position/index in second array  ([array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)), get the character from the found index of the first array.

Comment: perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598431/php-substitution-encoding-algorithm-using-cesar-cipher

Comment: @Jeff fixed, ta .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating an array that maps the original character to the encoded character:

```
$chars = [
    'a' => 'c',
    'b' => 'd',
    'c' => 'a',
    'd' => 'e',
    'e' => 'b',
];
```

Then you loop through the string and replace the characters:

```
$original  = 'acdc';

// Encrypt
$encrypted = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($original); $i++) {
    // If we find the character in our mapping array, use the mapped character.
    // If not, let's use the original character.
    $encrypted .= array_key_exists($original[$i], $chars) 
        ? $chars[$original[$i]]
        : $original[$i];
}

print_r($encrypted);
// caea
```

To decrypt it, we just needs to check if the character exists in the array and use the key instead:

```
// Decrypt
$decrypted = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($encrypted); $i++) {
    // Find the correct key
    $key = array_search($encrypted[$i], $chars);

    // If the character existed, use the key.
    // If not, use the original character.
    $decrypted .= $key !== false 
        ? $key
        : $encrypted[$i];
}

print_r($decrypted);
// acdc
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/vQAZj